# Retrieving a softlayer billing item cancellation request by fullyQualifiedDomainName

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking at retrieving a billing cancellation request using `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests`

I see in each request the fullyQualifiedDomainName is either in attachedHardware or attachedVirtualGuests.
 How do I code the objectFilter for this type of retrieval?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will now be able to filter using **fullyQualifiedDomainName**, you can use **hostname** and **domain** properties instead.

Try to retrieve the data you require by using the following REST requests:

**For attachedHardware**

Option 1:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[items[billingItem],ticket[attachedHardwareCount,attachedHardware]]&objectFilter={"ticket":{"attachedHardware":{"domain":{"operation":"domain.com"},"hostname":{"operation":"exampleName"}}}}
```

Option 2:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[items[billingItem],ticket[attachedHardwareCount,attachedHardware]]&objectFilter={"items":{"billingItem":{"domainName":{"operation":"domain.com"},"hostName":{"operation":"exampleName"}}},"ticket":{"attachedHardware":{"hostname":{"operation":"exampleName"}}}}
```

**For attachedVirtualGuests**

Option 1:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[items[billingItem],ticket[attachedVirtualGuestsCount,attachedVirtualGuests]]&objectFilter={"ticket":{"attachedVirtualGuests":{"domain":{"operation":"domain.com"},"hostname":{"operation":"exampleName"}}}}
```

Option 2:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[items[billingItem],ticket[attachedVirtualGuestsCount,attachedVirtualGuests]]&objectFilter={"items":{"billingItem":{"domainName":{"operation":"domain.com"},"hostName":{"operation":"exampleName"}}},"ticket":{"attachedVirtualGuests":{"hostname":{"operation":"exampleName"}}}}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Hi,  I choose option 2 on each. I used REST API URL https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[user,status,itemCount,items[billingItem],ticket[attachedVirtualGuestCount,attachedVirtualGuests,assignedUser]]&objectFilter={"items":{"billingItem":{"domainName":{"operation":"sl.cloud9.ibm.com"},"hostName":{"operation":"qbert-05"}}},"ticket":{"attachedVirtualGuestCount":{"operation":"> 0"}}}    and it retrieved the BAre Metal entry with the hostname and domain, but the stanza 'attachedVirtualGuestCount' => 0,   is 0.

Comment: I tried the hardware URL    https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/getAllCancellationRequests?objectMask=mask[user,status,itemCount,items[billingItem],ticket[attachedHardwareCount,attachedHardware,assignedUser]]&objectFilter={"items":{"billingItem":{"domainName":{"operation":"sl.cloud9.ibm.com"},"hostName":{"operation":"qbert-05"}}},"ticket":{"attachedHardwareCount":{"operation":"> 0"}}}   and it retrieved the same Bare Metal host entry with 'attachedHardwareCount' => 1, but 'attachedHardware' => [], there is not attachedHardware entries.

Comment: What is wrong with the objectFilter in VirtualGuest request and attachedHardware entries not returned when attaxhed HardwareCount is 1

Comment: Some counter properties cannot be used with filters and looks like this is happening with attachedVirtualGuestCount property. I apologies you for providing you that example, I removed it.

Comment: About attachedHardware = []   (empty), on my case I noticed that this happens when an attached hardware exists but it doesn't have a hostname and domain. It could be because the attached hardware isn't a baremetal, it could be another type of hardware. You can open a ticket in order to get further investigation if you wish.

Comment: In the meantime you can try with the other options.